# NodeJS + MongoDB - Starting mongodb server instance installed from npm

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running node.js on OSX and have just installed mongodb using command `npm install mongodb` under `myapp/node_modules` directory. According to mongodb official documenation, to start a mongodb you just have to execute `./mongodb/bin/mongo` on the command line. However I didn't see any directory called `'bin'` under the `node_modules/mongodb`..

Is there a special way to start a mongodb instance when it were bundled together with a node.js app? How would I start a mongodb server running on `mongodb://localhost/myapp`?

I'm currently also using matador (new mvc framework for node), and according to the documentation, we connect to the mongodb server this way:

```
// app/models/ApplicationModel.js
module.exports = require('./BaseModel').extend(function () {
  this.mongo = require('mongodb') 
  this.mongoose = require('mongoose')
  this.Schema = this.mongoose.Schema
  this.mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp') //CONNECT TO MONGODB SERVER...
})
```

At this moment I dont think I have mongodb server running, and don't really know how to set it up because of the issue above. Would appreciate any links, answers, and pointers to the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`npm install mongodb` is the command for installing Node.js **driver** for MongoDB. You'll have to install MongoDB **server** separately.

You can get it here: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Comment: @AGDM: that's because this was not asked.

Answer (score 1):

With NPM you got the mongo driver and not the mongodb. I use [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) to install softwares on my computer. To install mongodb without leaving console, you may use following command if you have chocolatey installed.

```
cinst mongodb
```